# How to find the sum of C(n;k) for odd k?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

How to calculate this expression?
$$\sum_{k \text{ odd}}{n\choose k}$$

I only just notice that, if n odd,then $$\sum_{k \text{ odd}}{n\choose k} = 2^{(n-1)}$$

Comment: Convert $\binom nk$ to $\binom {n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-1}k$

Comment: Just to be clear, are you also imposing the restriction that $n$ must be odd by saying "$n$ odd"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

$$S(n,x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k = (1+x)^n$$

we can evaluate the summation over only odd k of the binomial coefficients as:

$$\sum_{\text{odd }k}\binom{n}{k} = \frac{S(n,1) - S(n,-1)}{2} = 2^{n-1}$$